# ASP Classic page quit working

Tags: asp-classic

I've had a set of legacy pages running on my IIS7 server for at least a year. Sometime last week something changed and now this line:

```
Response.Write CStr(myRS(0).name) & "=" & Cstr(myRS(0).value)
```

which used to return nothing more exciting than the string: 'Updated=true' (the sproc processing input params, stores them to a table, checks for errors and when that's all done returns a success code by executing this statement:
select 'true' as [Updated]

Now my pageside error handler is being involved and offers:

```
myError=Error from /logQuizScore.asp
Error source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
Error number: 13
Error description: Type mismatch
```

Important to note that all lots of pages use the same framework - same db, same coding format, connecitonstrings and (so far as I can tell) all others are working.

Troubleshot to this point:

The call to the stored procedure is working correctly (stuff is stored to the given table). The output from the stored procedure is working correctly (i can execute a direct call with the given parameters and stuff works. I can see profiler calling and passing. I can replace all code with 'select 'true' as updated' and the error is the same.

everything up to the response.write statement above is correct.

So something changed how ADO renders that particular recordset.

So i try: Response.Write myRS.Item.count

and get:

Error number: 424
Error description: Object required

The recordset object seems not to be instantiating but the command object _did execute. Repeat - lots of other pages just the same basic logic to hit other sprocs without a problem.

full code snippet

```
set cmd1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd1.ActiveConnection = MM_cnCompliance4_STRING
cmd1.CommandText = "dbo._usp_UserAnswers_INSERT"
...
cmd1.CommandType = 4
cmd1.CommandTimeout = 0
cmd1.Prepared = true
set myRS = cmd1.Execute

Response.Write CStr(myRS(0).name) & "=" & Cstr(myRS(0).value)
```

Comment: A random thought that struck me - could it be that `'true'` is actually interpreted as a boolean, and therefore will not be cast to string? Have you tried executing something like `SELECT 'hello world' AS [Updated]`? Also, have you tried this? It might help you figure out why you're getting the type mismatch error... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525253.aspx

Comment: Did you already try replacing `cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT 'true' AS updated"` and `cmd1.CommandType = 1`? What happens behind `...`?

Comment: no change with either 'hello world' or 'select 1 as updated'. Beyond that - this page has been in service for years - the code hasn't changed.

fliburt's idea to change the CommandType - interesting - and it worked. The RecordSet object was created and output to the reponse.write line. The snipped part of the snippets was just the param list in the form of - cmd1.Parameters.Append cmd1.CreateParameter("@Score", 3, 1,4,cmd1__Score).

Comment: Man, that's a tough one. Did you already try to run your snippet in a simple vbscript outside the surrounding ASP code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the sproc has changed and returns a scalar instead of a result set.

Changing `CommandType = 1` (adCmdText) is need to match with your query changed to `SELECT 'whateveryouwannatry' AS [updated]`.

Since you stated that nothing in the asp code changed we can rule out that the return type of your command/sproc was altered by specifying an output parameter.

Comment: No change to spocs either. Sometime last week i changed a config setting on an different site but this site has been running unmodified for - literally - years.